# PHP mysqli_fetch_array() OOP style

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I want to run a SELECT query and fetch data as `associative array` and echo the fetched data.
In procedural style I would use `mysqli_fetch_array()`. But I am now trying `OOP style`.

I have tried this code:

```
$con=  new mysqli('localhost','root','','afiliate');
$query="SELECT * FROM product WHERE ID=? ";
$stmt->bind_param("i",$ID); /* $ID has a value, it's ok */
$stmt->execute();
$result=$con->query($query);
while($row=$result->fetch_row()){
    echo $row['name'];
}
```

And the error I get is:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_row() on boolean in /opt/lampp/htdocs/afiliate/product_details_individual.php on line 18

How can I **fetch data and echo them**?

Comment: have you tried `$result->fetch_array();`

Comment: `if (!$result=$con->query($query)) { // in case of unsuccess it returns false;`

Comment: @AshleyWrench >>>  Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on boolean in /opt/lampp/htdocs/afiliate/product_details_individual.php on line 18

Comment: You could also push the OOP further by using `$result->fetch_object('product');` but you will need to define a class `product` and have your db returning data matching the class definition.

Comment: you should use `prepare` method before `bind_param`. You don't do it. Your query not correct. `$result` get false. You use metod with false but object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing two conflicting things

```
$con=  new mysqli('localhost','root','','afiliate');
$query="SELECT * FROM product WHERE ID=? ";
$stmt->bind_param("i",$ID); /* $ID has a value, it's ok */
$stmt->execute();
```

So at this point `$stmt` is a [mysql_stmt object](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php). If you have [mysqlnd](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php) installed you can do this

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($row=$result->fetch_row()){
    echo $row['name'];
}
```

This line can't work in this code block

```
$result=$con->query($query);
```

The SQL you are passing is for a prepared statement and cannot be executed directly using `query()`. Your query will fail (returns `false` when there is an execution error) and, as a result, you get the error you mentioned

Comment: But this using this code, $row['name'] returns a NULL. var_dump($row['name']) just prints "NULL"

Comment: What about `var_dump($row);` ?

Comment: array(8) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(5) "watch" [2]=> string(10) "k bollo na" [3]=> string(8) "aer t 4t" [4]=> string(23) "product_images/fwef.png" [5]=> float(100) [6]=> string(7) "general" [7]=> float(5) }